# Saltar la pasarela de pago hacia pagina de agradecimiento en Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy usando Wordpress y WooCommerce para crear una tienda online. Una vez completados los pasos del checkout llega la hora del pago, y quiero que en ved de llevar a la pasarela de pago, la pagina te envie a una pagina personalizada o simplemente a la que viene por defecto.

Comment: Tendrías que averiguar sobre los hooks the tu theme (imagino que es storefront). Luego haces algunos intentos y si no logras nada, entonces vuelves y nos muestras tu código. Así como está formulada la pregunta nos pides que arreglemos un problema que no has investigado por tu cuenta

Comment: Lo de que "no has investigado por tu cuenta" es tu opinión. Si estoy pidiendo ayuda es por que me estoy volviendo loco con esto y no encuentro solución.

Comment: Pero no muestras código, no muestras hooks, no estás buscando cuál es el `action` que está asociado a ese botón, nos estás pidiendo que nosotros hagamos los ensayos prueba y error, y eso en woocommerce demora horas. Yo para ocultar el precio del carrito estuve un día completo porque hay 12 hooks asociados al famoso carro. Voy a ponerte una respuesta genérica porque no quiero que sientas que te estamos atacando gratuitamente

Answer (score 1):

Mira, depende mucho del theme. Woocommerce recomienda el theme Storefront, que lo hacen ellos mismos y tiene un acoplamiento brutal con el plugin mismo (algunas plantillas del theme se leen del plugin...).

En particular, casi todo lo que se dibuja en el theme está asociado a un hook.

Yo partiría por crear un theme hijo (child-theme). A lo mejor ya lo hiciste. Un child theme hereda todo del padre, por lo que podrías jugar con el child-theme sin arriesgarte a romper el theme principal, y por otro lado, cuando el theme principal se actualice, no vas a perder todo lo que cambiaste.

Los themes están en `wp-content/themes/` así que para acortar las rutas digamos que ese subdirectorio es `<THEMES>`. Dicho esto, vamos al ejemplo más inmediato, lo que pasa en el header.

Si revisas, verás que en el theme storefront hay `hooks` asociados a la acción `storefront_header`. En el archivo

```
<THEMES>/storefront/inc/woocommerce/storefront-woocommerce-template-hooks.php
```

Dice:

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_product_search', 40 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart',    60 );
```

En la plantilla

```
<THEMES>/storefront/header.php
```

Se ejecuta la acción:

```
  <header id="..." style="...">
    <?php
      do_action( 'storefront_header' );
    ?>
  </header>
```

Para entender el flujo:

La declaración de los hooks de arriba indica que se "enganchen" las funciones `storefront_product_search` y `storefront_header_cart` para gatillarse cuando se llame a la acción `storefront_header`.

En el header se llama a la acción, lo cual ejecuta las funciones "hookeadas" a ésta. En este ejemplo las funciones `storefront_product_search` y `storefront_header_cart` que en particular escriben la caja de búsqueda y el widget del carrito que va mostrando el total y se puede desplegar para ver el detalle.

Si tú quisieras que ocurra otra cosa en el header, en tu theme hijo (digamos que es `storefront-child`) en

```
<THEMES>/storefront-child/header.php
```

Quitarías o desengancharías los hooks antes de llamar a la acción `storefront_header`:

```
  <header id="..." style="...">
    <?php
      remove_action('storefront_header', 'storefront_product_search', 40);
      remove_action('storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60);

      do_action( 'storefront_header' );
    ?>
  </header>
```

El orden en que se han declarado (40 y 60) son importantes a la hora de desregistrarlas.

**Para tu caso particular**

A diferencia del header, que es ultra genérico y aparece en todas las páginas, te tocará bucear qué ocurre en el carrito. Aquí viene el acoplamiento brutal. **La plantilla del carrito no está en el theme storefront sino en el plugin woocommerce**. Eso me parece de locos.

En fin. Estoy mirando el plugin y me parece que está en

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php
```

En tu child-theme, para sobreescribir esa plantilla tendrías que crear un subdirectorio woocommerce, y dentro de él la ruta relativa. **No es intuitivo** porque la ruta tendría que ser:

```
 <THEMES>/storefront-child/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
```

(Cuando el sentido común indica que debiera ser `<THEMES>/storefront-child/templates/...`)

La plantilla original **está llena de actions**

- woocommerce_cart_actions
- woocommerce_after_cart_contents
- woocommerce_after_cart_table
- woocommerce_cart_collaterals
- woocommerce_after_cart

Y cabe suponer que hay algunos hooks colgando de tales acciones. Tendrías que encontrar el hook, (en el theme original o en el plugin woocommerce) que dibuja el botón de checkout actual y desregistrarlo(s), y añadir en tu plantilla `cart.php` el link que quieres.

Tendrás que buscar algo que empiece con (por ejemplo) `add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals'`. Pero puede que sea más complicado y esté declarado como (ej):

```
$prefix = 'woocommerce';
$section = 'cart';
add_action( $prefix.'_'.$section.'_collaterals', 'funcion_que_dibuja_boton-checkout', 50);
```

Y eso complica todo. Conlleva harta búsqueda y mucha prueba y error hasta dar con la acción adecuada y su(s) respectivo hook.

Sólo me queda desearte suerte en la búsqueda.

## Una posible solución

Aparentemente el botón "checkout" se compone de varias plantillas que en su conjunto constituyen un formulario. El formulario envía los datos de la transacción a una URL predeterminada por WooComerce.

El inicio del formulario está en

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php
```

Y dice:

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

El atributo `action` dicta adonde se envía al cliente. WooCommerce entregará un valor para `wc_get_checkout_url()` acorde a la transacción. Por ejemplo si se trata de un pago contra entrega no hay pasarela de pago. Productos de tipo virtual no tienen un costo de envío, etc etc.

Posiblemente podrías jugar creando medios de pago en el dashboard de WooCommerce, pero la manera más corta es editar esa plantilla pisándola con una plantilla en tu theme, que pondrías en:

```
<THEMES>/storefront-child/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php
```

Copias la plantilla completa y sólo cambias el atributo `action` para enviar todos los datos de checkout adonde te acomode. Por ejemplo:

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url('http://mipasarela.com/pagar.php' ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Ojalá funcione.

Comment: Sigo buscando actualmente en los .php. Esto es un Mare Magnum de código infernal. Gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta!

Comment: Encontré una plantilla donde podrías sobreescribir el destino del formulario de pago. Veamos si te resulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: He probado a hacerlo pero me sigue dando problemas con PayPal. El error dice:  'Error PayPal (2): Ocurrió un error (2) al procesar tu pago en PayPal. Por favor, contacta con el propietario de la tienda para obtener ayuda.'

Comment: He cambiado el metodo de pago a Stripe, para tarjeta de credito normal. Dice 'Metodo de pago no valido'

Comment: Ahí no sé cómo ayudarte. A mí me ha tocado modificar pedacitos de Storefront, pero nunca integrar medios de pago. Siempre ponía "pago contra entrega" o con transferencia bancaria para hacer el flujo completo y olvidarme de esa parte

Comment: No se muy bien como lo he hecho pero he conseguido que mediante el pago con cupones o contrareembolso funcione y vaya solito a la pagina predefinida. Aun así gracias!